# what is a balanced binary tree and how does it differ than a complete one?

Tags: binary-tree

can you please explain to me what is a balanced binary tree i read many explanations and still didn't get. and can we say that a complete binary tree is a balanced binary tree?

according to Wikipedia :

> A balanced binary tree has the minimum possible maximum height (a.k.a. depth) for the leaf nodes, because for any given number of leaf nodes the leaf nodes are placed at the greatest height possible.[clarification needed]

but i still did not get this definition can you please explain to me what is a balanced binary tree and give me some examples

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3515/two-definitions-of-balanced-binary-trees

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about data structure theory, not programming. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [balanced binary tree](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads//HTML/balancedbitr.html) is one where every leaf is no more than a certain amount further from the root than every other leaf node. For example, an [AVL tree](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads//HTML/avltree.html) is a balanced binary search tree where:

1. Its left and right subtrees are balanced.
2. The difference between the depth of the left and right subtrees from every node is no more than 1.

The following is an AVL tree:

```
       r
     /   \
    a     b
   / \     
  c   d
```

In terms of your initial question, yes, a [complete binary tree](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads//HTML/completeBinaryTree.html) is a balanced binary tree, but not the other way around. A complete binary tree is a binary tree where every level, except possibibly the last is completely filled, and all the nodes are as far left as possible. As another example:

```
       r
     /   \
    a     b
   / \   / 
  c   d e
```